# Migration request

Tags: support, status-declined, migration, specific-question

My [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27568/how-to-reduce-the-cost-of-search-based-on-previous-bfs) haven't been answered, even after I set a bounty, no new answers been added.
Pleas migrate it to [Programers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It seems you have received an answer; do you have reason to doubt its accuracy?

Comment: @Raphael Yeah, part of the cases could be solved with matrix transformation, how ever it does not cover all of it. So yeah, "there is no way" is unacceptable answer by me.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is on-topic here. We don't normally migrate questions unless they should be closed where they are.

Your question is at best marginal for Programmers since it's about an algorithm from a theoretical point of view.

We occasionally migrate questions to [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), if they are about theory, research-level, have not received a satisfactory answer after a few days, and the asker is willing. Your question doesn't look research-level to me, but I'm happy to be contradicted by experts in the topic.

If you want better answers, my first advice is to listen to the feedback given to you. Have you explored Juho's suggestions? How about editing your question to clarify it as he suggests? IPlant's answer might not give the full story, but it gives suggestions that you give no evidence of having taken into account either.

Comment: Can you point it out to me, what suggestions can I take to improve the question?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman, Gilles already explained some things you can do to improve your question.  "my first advice is to listen to the feedback given to you. Have you explored Juho's suggestions? How about editing your question to clarify it as he suggests? IPlant's answer might not give the full story, but it gives suggestions that you give no evidence of having taken into account either."  In the future, I encourage you to read more carefully.

Comment: @D.W. What am I missing? For my opinion Juno been completely in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman, I don't understand why you think Juho is completely wrong.  Again, Gilles already told you what to do. (1) Explore Juho's suggestions. (2) Edit the question to clarify the problem, based on his questions. (3) Edit the question to describe what you've looked at and whether they do/don't meet your need. For instance, you might add a statement "I've looked at incremental A* but it doesn't meet my requirements because (...)" -- you fill in the "(..."), we can't guess.  From what I can see Juho's suggestions look quite reasonable, so if you don't think so, you need to explain why not.